# What is Vec<_>?

Tags: generics, rust, syntax

I have seen `Vec<_>` a couple of times already. For example:

```
let a = "line1\r\nline2\nline3";
println!("{:?}", a.lines().collect::<Vec<_>>());
```

But what does that 'uncertain face' `<_>` mean?

I'm used to a typename in angle brackets, but what type can that be?
The only meaning of underscore that I'm aware of is from Python as a name for an unused variable.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It means "Rust compiler, infer what type goes into the `Vec`". And it is indeed analogous to the unused variable in Python (and in Rust itself), in that it represents a placeholder for a type, like it can represent a placeholder for a variable name.

You can find an explanation in *The Rust Programming Language* chapter about [iterator consumers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/iterators.html#consumers):

> Using a _ will let you provide a partial hint:
>
> `let one_to_one_hundred = (1..101).collect::<Vec<_>>();` This says
>   "Collect into a `Vec<T>`, please, but infer what the `T` is for me." `_` is
>   sometimes called a "type placeholder" for this reason.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason generics chapter in the docs doesn't say anything about parameter type inference.

Comment: Is there any documentation somewhere specifically about the `_` syntax? I can't find any. I only find text where it is used when iterators are explained.

Comment: @Lii I think that's the only place it's mentioned right now. The issue on github for documenting the feature has been closed adding that paragraph to the iterators section: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/22293