# What does it mean to instantiate a Rust generic with an underscore?

Tags: generics, rust

While working with serde_json for reading json documents, I wrote the following line of code to obtain the result of unwrapping the return value of `serde_json::from_str`:

```
fn get_json_content(content_s: &str) -> Option<Value> {
    let ms: String = serde_json::from_str(content_s).unwrap; // <--

    match serde_json::from_str(content_s) {
        Ok(some_value) => Some(some_value),
        Err(_) => None
    }
}
```

As you can see, I forgot the `()` on the end of the call to `unwrap`, which resulted in the following error:

> error: attempted to take value of method
>   `unwrap` on type `core::result::Result<_, serde_json::error::Error>`
>
> ```
> let ms: String = serde_json::from_str(content_s).unwrap;
> ```

But when I looked at this a bit further, the thing that struck me as odd was:

```
core::result::Result<_, serde_json::error::Error>
```

I understand what underscore means in a match context, but to instantiate a generic? So what does this mean? I couldn't find any answers in the Rust book, or reference, or a web search.

Comment: See also [What is Vec<_>?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34363984/155423).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's a placeholder. In this context, it means that there isn't enough information for the compiler to infer a type.

You can use this in your code to make the compiler infer the type for you. For example:

```
pub fn main() {
    let letters: Vec<_> = vec!["a", "b", "c"]; // Vec<&str>
}
```

This is particularly handy because in many cases you can avoid using the ["turbofish operator"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect):

```
fn main() {
    let bar = [1, 2, 3];
    let foos = bar.iter()
                  .map(|x| format!("{}", x))
                  .collect::<Vec<String>>(); // <-- the turbofish
}
```

vs

```
fn main() {
    let bar = [1, 2, 3];
    let foos: Vec<_> = bar // <-- specify a type and use '_' to make the compiler
                           //     figure the element type out
            .iter()
            .map(|x| format!("{}", x))
            .collect(); // <-- no more turbofish
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I prefer to be explicit about all types, because omitting types to me just makes code unreadable, which is why I always specify types in let bindings. I know this is seems like an anti pattern in Rust, but I waste too much time in figuring out the types of things, so I'd rather be explicit.

Comment: @Zephilim: There's an interesting argument about type elision; some argue types are necessary for understanding, others that they clutter the real information. It's a very personal choice in the end :)

Comment: Well you can guess what side of the argument I'm on. It wouldn't be so bad if I had a decent IDE that could go to the definition of things, but thats not my setup at the moment. I'm just using Atom as a text editor which can't do this. I tried VisualRust, but that's hopeless at the moment.

Comment: FYI, for the turbofish, you could probably use `::<Vec<_>>` instead of `::<Vec<String>>`.