# What does <'_> mean in Rust?

Tags: rust, syntax

In this code from [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) examples:

```rust
use std::fmt;

struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl fmt::Debug for Point {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        f.debug_struct("Point")
         .field("x", &self.x)
         .field("y", &self.y)
         .finish()
    }
}

let origin = Point { x: 0, y: 0 };

assert_eq!(format!("The origin is: {origin:?}"), "The origin is: Point { x: 0, y: 0 }");
```

What does `<'_>` mean in `f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>`?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `'` denotes that it is a Lifetime: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime.html

This is usually written as `'a` where `a` is the name of the lifetime (like the name of the variable, can be any name)

The `_` means that the compiler can infer the name/type. (so you don't have to figure it out, makes it easier)
You can find more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37215830/2037998

The `<>` is because of Generics. You can see that in the docs it is defines as [`impl<'a> Formatter<'a>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html)

Comment: Why do we need to specify a lifetime here? And does the "guess it for me" not the default action if we specify nothing ?

Comment: The compiler always needs to know what it is. So if it can not infer/guess it from the code around it, it will prompt you that you need to add more info. Aka you need to specify it.
I'm not sure how you would create that case with `Debug`. But if you are using it somewhere else, avoiding lifetimes in the beginning when learning Rust is recommended. Just use `variable_name.clone()` usually solves it.