# Store any type in a struct field

Tags: rust

I'm working on code like the following:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct CallbackWithArgs<T> {
    callback: Box<Fn(&mut T) -> ()>,
    arg: RefCell<T>,
}

struct S {
    args: CallbackWithArgs<_>,
}
```

The compiler has an error:

```
error[E0121]: the type placeholder `_` is not allowed within types on item signatures
 --> src/main.rs:9:28
  |
9 |     args: CallbackWithArgs<_>,
  |                            ^ not allowed in type signatures
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Please also add the compiler error.

Comment: "So could anyone enlighten me with the correct way to do this?" What is "this"? What is it that you want to do?

Comment: Why would you not make `S` generic to allow any type?

Comment: The compiler error is something like `expect `std::any::Any + 'static`, found `std::any::Any``. Thus, after I set lifetime properly, this error has been fixed. I think the problem's gone. However, I'm still a little bewildered with the combination of lifetime and trait declaration in generic type declaration.

Comment: [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/) has an [*entire chapter*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-00-generics.html) on generics.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `_` in a struct declaration; the compiler needs to know the struct's size at compile time.

If you want the type to be generic you can add a type parameter to `S` just as you did to `CallbackWithArgs`:

```
struct CallbackWithArgs<T> {
    callback: Box<Fn(&mut T) -> ()>,
    arg: RefCell<T>,
}

struct S<T> {
    args: CallbackWithArgs<T>,
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c87c1a3fb6908c01a8e3475a10869653&version=stable)

For an explanation of `_`, see [What is Vec<_>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363984/what-is-vec)

Comment: Yeap, I know I can't use `_` in that place. I just wanna express the idea of `Any`. Thanks anyway.