# Difference between Vec<_> and Vec<T>

Tags: rust

I've been working my way through the book Rust in Action and i've seen The generic syntax `Vec<T>` where T is any type in my understanding but also i've seen `Vec<_>` which I read that infers the type based off of the contents of the vector. I was wondering what the distinction between `Vec<T>` and `Vec<_>` is because I can't tell the difference between them as they appear to do the same thing? Or their descriptions would seem to lead me to believe. Why would I use one vs the other?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363984/what-is-vec

Answer (score 3):

The `_` is called a [wildcard](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#wildcard-pattern). It basically tells Rust to just deduce the type needed, and that's it.

For `Vec<T>` it's a [generic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics.html) it does two things, it names the type, but also is a generic parameter for any type. Since you don't know what type it can be, you use `T` to tell in places where it should be that type, where to get the information from (in a sense).

So `_` means any type, but deduced in context (a unique type), `T` is a generic type, and can be many types (a new generation is done for each separate type it encounters).

Answer (score 0):

`Vec<T>` could be defined as (the actual definition is more complex):

```
pub struct Vec<T> {
    buf: RawVec<T>,
    len: usize,
}
```

As such, it's called `Vec<T>` because that's how the generic struct is defined.
When creating a `Vec`, you have to specify what the type of the elements are:

```
let x: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3];
```

Here, the type annotation isn't actually needed, since the compiler can infer it for us.

Let's say we want to obtain all of the command line arguments as a `Vec`. We could try:

```
let args = std::env::args().collect();
```

...but that fails with:

```text
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/main.rs:2:9
  |
2 |     let args = std::env::args().collect();
  |         ^^^^ consider giving `args` a type
```

since we didn't specify which container to collect the arguments into: `.collect()` can collect the iterator elements into a `Vec<T>`, a `Box<[T]>`, a `LinkedList<T>`, [and many more](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#implementors). Let's specify a type:

```
let args: Vec<String> = std::env::args().collect();
```

This compiles, but we can make this a bit simpler: we can do

```
let args: Vec<_> = std::env::args().collect();
```

and get the same effect, since the `_` tells the compiler to infer what the type is. Since there is only one possible type inferred by the compiler, it replaces the `_` with `String`. `Vec<_>` isn't a type, it's a partial type that makes the compiler fill in the `_`.